# Detect if iOS App is written in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, jailbreak, cydia

Im developing a tool that tries to dump header classes for a jailbroken device on an App.
I'm using [Clutch](https://www.google.com.ph/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=Cydia%20Clutch&es_th=1), but sometimes Clutch fails to some newer apps, I'm thinking of integrating some tools other than Clutch.
So, I need to determine at first if the binary is written in Swift, so that I can switch to the right tool to execute.

My question is,
**Is there a way, like a command tool to determine if an iOS App Binary is written in Swift?** 
Is there really much difference in how the binary is built when it's in Swift compare to just Obj-C?

Comment: Some apps are built with a mix of swift and objective-c. What are you gonna do then?

Comment: You have no right whatsoever to dump header files for any application that I have written and that is on the app store.

Comment: this is a pentesting tool that determines if an app is vulnerable to some common security issues. see www.idbtool.com

Comment: thanks Nicolas, I think my priority right now is, as long as I know if an app is written with Swift code in it then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [nm tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nm_(Unix)) to print app symbol table. If you search for `swift`, for example using `grep`:

```
nm YourApp | grep swift
```

It will print something like this (and many more):

```
U __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFoundation
```

For an 100% Objective-C app the result will be empty. However, you can't tell if the code is 100% Swift because for mixed objc + swift apps the result will be similar to a swift app.

Comment: I think this one is a best fit solution. Thanks Adam

Answer (score 7):

Inside the .app file there is a _CodeSignature folder. Inside there is a CodeResources file. If you open that as text you will see that it contains `Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib`

I believe this indicates that it has been built with swift.

Comment: if iOS13 up, it not's contains Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib